# Overlapping columns in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

The bottom-left and bottom-right expressions don't need to be so far apart. Can I make them sit closer together? I guess that means making the outer columns overlap the middle column.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & x_1 + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2 + \frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}}x_3 \arrow[equals, d] \\
        & 0 \arrow[equals, ld] \arrow[equals, rd] & \\
        x_1 + \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}x_2 + \frac{a_{23}}{a_{21}}x_3 & & x_1 + \frac{a_{32}}{a_{32}}x_2 + \frac{a_{33}}{a_{31}}x_3
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-3em]
        & x_1 + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2 + \frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}}x_3 \arrow[equals, d] \\
        & 0 \arrow[equals, ld] \arrow[equals, rd] & \\
        x_1 + \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}x_2 + \frac{a_{23}}{a_{21}}x_3 & & x_1 + \frac{a_{32}}{a_{32}}x_2 + \frac{a_{33}}{a_{31}}x_3
    \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think that's it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to @Bernard's solution, you could enclose the top entry in `\mathclap` to eliminate its width. Note: `\mathclap` requires the `mathtools` package, which you can use in place of `amsmath`.

[image]

This has the advantage of only eliminating the width of specific entries without adjusting the column spacing of the diagram as a whole.

You could reduce the `column sep` value as well if you desire. In addition, you could enclose *part* of an expression in `\mathllap` (overlap left) or `\mathrlap` (overlap right):

```
x_1 + \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}x_2 + \mathrlap{\frac{a_{23}}{a_{21}}x_3}
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & \mathclap{x_1 + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2 + \frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}}x_3} \arrow[equals, d] \\
        & 0 \arrow[equals, ld] \arrow[equals, rd] & \\
        x_1 + \frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}x_2 + \frac{a_{23}}{a_{21}}x_3 & & x_1 + \frac{a_{32}}{a_{32}}x_2 + \frac{a_{33}}{a_{31}}x_3
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```